# Does HttpClientHandler.ClientCertificates cause only leaf certificate or entire certificate hierarchy to be sent to server?

Tags: authentication, ssl, asp.net-core, .net-core, ssl-certificate

In .net core 2.2 (or above), one can write following code (on client side) to post a json request to and get json response from a REST service that has mutual TLS authentication enabled:

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

//Load Leaf Client Certificate
var clientCertPath = @"<pfx-file-path>";
var password = "<password>";
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertPath, password);

clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);

clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, arg3, arg4) =>
{
    //Validate web server cert
    return true; 
};

var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
var requestJson = "<json string>";
var content = new StringContent(requestJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = client.PostAsync("<web-url>", content).Result;
var responsString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Note the following line in the code that attaches the client leaf certificate:

```
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
```

My questions are:

1. Does .net core framework send only the leaf client certificate (and not include intermediate certs and root certs) to the REST service? Or does it include all certificates in the client certificate hierarchy (i.e. leaf cert, intermediate certs and root certs)?
2. Does this behavior change based on the client platform (i.e. if the client is running on windows or linux)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supposed to send the leaf and intermediates (but not the Root).

After the client certificate is chosen (which is an easy algorithm when there's only one thing in the collection) SslStream uses X509Chain to build up the rest of the chain so it can include the intermediates. It works best (but isn't strictly required) when the client machine trusts its own certificate (and can fully resolve the chain to show that trust).

If the chain build ends in an untrusted root (that is, it finished at a self-signed certificate) then the intermediates are still sent; but .NET Core 2.x had [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37927) on Linux (and maybe macOS) where if the chain ended without the self-signed certificate it sent one less certificate than intended (it erroneously counted the last cert as the root to not send, no matter what). In a standard 3 deep chain (root -> issuer -> end entity) that means it looks the same as "only sent the leaf cert".

Comment: Interesting! What is the rationale for sending only leaf and intermediate certs? If the server would like to validate the incoming client cert based on the common name and the root authority, how can it do that with .net core clients? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The TLS spec says not to bother sending the root, because the other side either knows it and can build the chain, or doesn’t and won’t trust it.

Comment: @bartonjs is there is way to force send root CA as well

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch Nope. Well, not unless it’s a self-signed cert.

Comment: @bartonjs its a self signed for sure. I asked a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318339/force-send-root-ca-with-request

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch I realized the ambiguity in my statement a few minutes after writing it. If the server cert is self-signed the root is sent trivially (one cert is sent at minimum). Other than that case, there is nothing you can do to get .NET to send a root in TLS