# Force Send Root CA with Request

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2, x509certificate

We have third party API provider that provided an SOAP API. They have provided 3 certificates,

1. Client Cert
2. Intermediate Cert
3. Root Cert

All certs are installed locally. They have provided a pfx cert with password. We have uploaded this pfx in SOAP UI tool and run a request it worked. Then we tried the same with .NET request,

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
var client = new ServiceReference1.myClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBinary, certificatePassword);
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
```

It failed with handshake failure error.

Then we monitored both SOAP UI traffic and .NET code traffic using WireShark.

[image]

Clearly the .NET is not sending Root CA. The problem is that request is rejected by the third party API if Root CA is not present in the request. How can force send ROOT CA.

Comment: .NET behaves exactly as it should. Receiving party should have your root installed. If it is not installed, then your client certificate cannot be validated up to trusted CA regardless you send or do not send root certificate. There is no practical need to send root CA cert.

Comment: @Crypt32 Then SOAP UI is doing wrong? I got the response from third party that my client should do what SOAP UI is doing. This is the only reason they are rejecting. I thought there should be a way in .NET to send ROOT CA as part of request.

Comment: `Then SOAP UI is doing wrong?` -- it does what is optional per RFC 5246 §7.4.6 and §7.4.2. Root CA cert can be omitted from cert list. I suspect that client certificate validation logic is flawed on third party side if they require root CA to be sent by client.

Comment: Don't you think .NET should also implement optional part of RFC 5246 §7.4.6 and §7.4.2 as some server might requires this?

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to require the CA cert to be sent and I'm not aware of *any* server that requires it.

Comment: No matter what the problem is, sending/not sending the root CA is certainly not the solution. Per RFC8446 (TLS 1.3) at "4.4.2.  Certificate" says: "Because
   certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed
   independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
   omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
   possess any omitted certificates."

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk its not about HTTP servers, it about the API protected using certificate and Root CA cert is not public. Unfortunately, it was third party that implemented their API in that way that requires us to send all 3 APIs. In short, they want us to send all 3 certs and SOAP UI is doing the same, so we need to do the same.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I understand but what can we do as a consumer of the API? I saw some APIs support omit root ca like https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sva/9.0.7?topic=stanza-omit-root-cert

Comment: See SAP blog
https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/certificate_client_S.png 
https://blogs.sap.com/2021/07/22/how-to-troubleshoot-client-certificate-authentication-for-inbound-communication-to-cloud-integration-using-wireshark/

Comment: "what can we do as a consumer of the API?" If you have a specific problem with a specific API it seems to me your first step should be to ask the producer side of that API. you say "The problem is that request is rejected by the third party API if Root CA is not present in the request. " but it is not even clear how you come to this conclusion. Handshake failure can be ton of things. Did you do two handshakes, just differing by the CA root being there or not, and getting different replies? (your wireshark screenshots are lacking tons of details)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek have you seen SAP screenshot in comments?

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch It is not a good idea to use images and even less to have parts of your question needing to access remote links to understand it. Please put all relevant data, **as text**, in your question (not in comments).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have shared SAP blog post where it mentioned that it is mandatory to include Root CA. Also, I have found POSTMAN is sending root CA. So, there should be a way to send ROOT CA with any library/language/framework(if not .NET)